# c++17: function template lambda specialization

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, specialization

Motivation: one has a function that accepts either a lambda or a value (for simplicity it can be either `const char *` or `std::string`) like following

```cpp
template <typename LambdaOrValue>
void Function(LambdaOrValue &&lambda_or_value) {
  // The idea here is to have sort of a magic that
  // evaluates a lambda if an argument is actually
  // a lambda or do nothing otherwise
  if (Evaluate(std::forward<LabmdaOrValue>(lambda_or_value)) ==
               std::string("pattern"))
    // Do something
}
```

I'm struggling to properly implement a function `Evaluate()` i.e. to make the code below compile. In particular, which return value to use in the "value"-based implementation to
preserve the type (e.g. `const char *` or `std::string`)

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
decltype(std::declval<T>()()) Evaluate(T &&t) {
  return t();
}

template <typename T>
T Evaluate(T &&t) {  // <<--- What return type use here to preserve the type
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << Evaluate("test") << std::endl;
  std::cout << Evaluate([]() { return "lambda"; }) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have access to C++17, why not use `std::is_invocable`, `if constexpr` and `decltype(auto)` combo?

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto Evaluate(T &&t) -> decltype(auto){
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<T>)
        return t();
    else
        return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

Comment: Of course, thank you so much! I had all ingredients but could not make a potion out of it.